# Android - java connected via socket programming. dataoutputstream write does not fail on the java side after the device is disconnected from network

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I have a android device sending data to Java server via TCP connection. I verify whether the device is connected to server by writing in the device output stream every 10 seconds. But when the android device is disconnected from Wifi, the server could still write for sometime - after that it would fail. But if i terminate the application, the server write to the client fails right away. Any suggestions on where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The first write to a broken connection almost certainly won't fail, due to TCP buffering. A subsequent write will fail. It could take quite a few, or a lot of data. If you terminate the receiver it sends something to the sender that it can detect. If the connection just breaks, TCP has to time out retries.

Comment: So is there a way out to identify broken connection while the device is still up but disconnected from server ?